# Why does comparing the same numbers not equal true?

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to check the group indices of 4 objects.

```
clickedList[0].group == clickedList[1].group == clickedList[2].group == clickedList[3].group
```

When the group is 0 or 1 it works. 2 and 3 are not working. I opened the console and when I check the value of 3 == 3 == 3 it returns false. What is happening here?

Comment: you can not chain copmparisons that way. the next comparison compares the result of the  one before and this is a boolean value.

Comment: Ah, so the 0 and 1 cases are just being turned to bools.

Comment: `3 == 3 == 3` is same as `true == 3` after first comparison evaluates

Answer (score 1):

3 == 3 == 3 is false as it is evaluated as follows:
((3 == 3) == 3) implies (true == 3) implies false as 3 is not true, where as 1 is considered true according to javascript.

Note: Javascript is a dynamically weakly typed language and thus I would recommend you to use triple-equals (===) in most cases to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: it is more `(3 === 3) == 3`. `===` has [left associativity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Precedence_And_Associativity), if it follows the same operator, like all others in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, once the first comparison is done the boolean result is compared to the following number. I'm now using the following instead

```
clickedList[0].group === clickedList[1].group && clickedList[1].group === clickedList[2].group && clickedList[2].group === clickedList[3].group
```